# Typescript disable compile on save in vs 2015 ctp 6

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I need to know how to disable compile on save for typescript files?

Comment: to disable it just upgrade to RTM because they broke it :-/
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1581065/typescript-compile-output-into-single-file-not-working-on-save ;-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Typescript compilation is enabled by default.
You can do next to disable it:

1. Select and click 'Unload Project' menu item.
2. Select unloaded project and click 'Edit .kproj'.
3. Add new 'PropertyGroup' node to projects root node:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ...>
...
<PropertyGroup>
<TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>False</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
</PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Is their a way to compile the script on save but not save the .js file ?

Comment: In 3rd point should be "add new 'PropertyGroup'" not "ProjectGroup".  I wanted to edit it, but StackOverflow doesn't allow to make such small changes

Answer (score 6):

#### For loose files (outside of a project)

Tools -> Options

- Text Editor

  - TypeScript

    - Project

`[ ]` Automatically compile TypeScript files which are not part of a project

#### For projects

Right-click the project -> Properties

Select the "TypeScript Build" tab (on the left)

Uncheck "Compile on save" under the "General" heading

Comment: To be clear there is no Typescript Build tab for Asp.net 5 projects.

Comment: For the new VS2015 when using ASP.Net 5 projects, this setting can be found on the `Build` tab as `Compile TypeScript on build`.

Comment: Compile typescript on build doesn not prevent js fiels to be created on save. It seems that TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled still doens't work on ASP.NET 5 projects

Comment: More details about "Compile on save" in ASP.NET 5 projects can be found in this article: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-TypeScript-With-ASP.NET-5#user-content-compile-on-save